# How to make this function thread safe?

Tags: java

```
public class Sol {



    static Map<Integer, List<String>> emap;
    static List<Integer> sortSalaries(List<List<String>> workers) {
        List<Integer> res = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        emap = new HashMap<>();
        for (List<String> e: workers)
            emap.put(Integer.parseInt(e.get(0)), e);

        for(List<String> worker: workers )
        {
         //accessing workers
         .....
        }


        Collections.sort(res);

        return res;


    }

    public static int dfs(int eid) {
        List<String> employee = emap.get(eid);
        int salary=0;
        String ans = employee.get(3);
        for (int i=0;i<ans.length();i=i+2)

        {
            // accesing emap
          ......
        }

        return salary;
    }


}
```

Do i have to use synchronized keyword to make it thread safe. Do i have to use Vector and Hashtable if method is synchronized.

Alternatively, What if i use Vector and Hashtable, move the `emap` variable to `sortSalaries()` and pass it to `dfs()`. Is it okay **if i not use** synchronized keyword in this case..

Comment: What about this is threaded?

Comment: I can not see any `run` method? Is this actually a Thread?

Comment: These functions are called from threads.. so i want to make sure, correct data is returned

Comment: Why do you use `static` method? Create single instance of this class is not OK for you?

Comment: @mzz: first , do you understand why these methods are not thread-safe if called from multiple threads?

Comment: @SabirKhan this is the reason right https://www.programcreek.com/2014/02/how-to-make-a-method-thread-safe-in-java/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked you question in comment that - **do you understand why these methods are not thread-safe if called from multiple threads?** and you pointed me to a link without specifying that if you really understood it or not and why do you think that your class is not thread safe so I am providing a little bit of background instead of directly answering the question.

**A Bit of Short Discussion**

Any class or its methods might become not thread safe when you **start sharing data**  among runner / calling threads. Your class by default is thread - safe if no data is shared among threads so easiest way to make your class thread - safe is to **stop sharing data** among threads and in your case, its going to be removal of - `emap` ( because its a class state and used in methods )  & `List<List<String>> workers` ( This is what I am not sure of since its a reference passed on from caller and different method calls will be working on same instance or might be different instances are passed to this method ) and replace these by method local variables.

Method local variables are thread - safe by default since new instances are created and destroyed for each call.

if you can't do that or not feasible , follow oleg.cherednik's answer to synchronize for variable - `emap` - either at block level or method level. Do remember that there are various ways to synchronize in Java with `synchronized` keyword being easiest.

Now for method parameters - `List<List<String>> workers` & `int eid` , synchronization for `eid` is not needed since you are simply reading it and not updating & also its not pass by reference but pass by value due to type being primitive.

Synchronization for access to `List<List<String>> workers` is needed if you are passing same list instance to calls of this method from different threads. Refer to [Gray's Answer - Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22645763/3850730)   and this point is missed in oleg.cherednik's answer. You are better judge if synchronization would be needed or not for this reference.

Its easy to assume that `List` iteration is thread- safe ( since you are not updating the list ) but that might not always be true . [Refer this question and all answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38845778/thread-safety-when-iterating-through-an-arraylist-using-foreach)  for detailed discussion.

So summary is this -  you start implementing thread - safety for your class by first analyzing if some objects are shared among threads or not. If objects are shared , read / write to those objects need to be synchronized ( to make it atomic & provided those objects are not already thread - safe ) . If no objects are shared - its already thread safe . Also, try to create your classes with already thread - safe data structures , that way you will have less work to do.

`java.lang.NullPointerException` ( NPE ) point of oleg.cherednik's answer stands too.

Comment: Evethough a refernce is passed to List<List<String>> workers, workers is still a local variable (method arguments are local variable ) and it's passed to a new copy of workers right ?? So sync is not needed for workers, right?

Comment: nopes, its not method local variable & that I why I pointed to Gray's answer for other question. Synchronization would be needed for that.

Comment: when a thread A, calls sortSalaries passing a reference of workers, is it possible for thread A, to change contents of workers when sortSalaries is being executed ? No, right ? sortSalaries must finish execution for thread A to resume execution ?

Comment: @mzz: forget about modification, iteration itself might not be thread safe. It all depends how you synchronize in this method. This is just a point to be considered ( not just to be left without giving due consideration ) , might not be applicable in your case. So I would say , show your final changed code and then we can discuss.

Answer (score 1):

1. Protect `emap` from outer access
2. Init `emap` to exclude `NPE`

Example:

```
public final class Sol {

    private static final Map<Integer, List<String>> emap = new HashMap<>();

    static List<Integer> sortSalaries(List<List<String>> workers) {
        synchronized (Foo.class) {
            for (List<String> e : workers)
                emap.put(Integer.parseInt(e.get(0)), e);
        }

        // do smth, not access emap
    }

    public static synchronized int dfs(int eid) {
        // do smth with accessing emap
    }
}
```

In `sortSalaries` you can minimize `synchoronized` block with `for loop`. In `dfs` you access `emap` in different places of the method and therefore you have to synchoonized enire method.

Using either `ConcurrentHashMap` or `Vector` do not help here, becuase betwee `get/set` elements to the collection, they could be changed, which is not OK for `dfs` method: it should feeze `emap` when it's called.

Comment: im aslo using res arraylist in sortSalaries, so the entire func has to be syncronized right. can you tell why there is no need to use vector or hashtable more clearly

Comment: @mzz : `res` is a method local variable , a new instance is created for each method call ( without sharing instances ) so no synchronization is needed for that.